# How to get pod's TCP or WebSocket connection count on Google Kubernetes Engine?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

Is there any way to get pod's TCP or WebSocket connection count on Google Kubernetes Engine? My point is, i need to create and scale new pod instance if my pod's connection count (not request) is over 2000? I read GKE's and Google StackDriver's documents but there is no info about connection count.

Answer (score 0):

At this point, I did not see any metric that you can monitor on Stackdriver monitoring to address TCP connection count for pods. One possible route is to use [Autoscaling Deployments with Custom Metrics](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/custom-metrics-autoscaling).

Since metric is not available, you could also place a feature [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) for the Stackdriver Monitoring team to work on.